# How is meta participation counted?

Tags: support, users

On Meta Stack Overflow there is ["participation"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation) tab instead of ["reputation"](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation) tab on Stack Overflow. How is participation counted?

Comment: @user0000000 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation

Comment: @KevinPanko Those numbers are just our reputation copied from the main site.  Where exactly are you looking?

Comment: @nicael "Counted" implies numbers.

Comment: @nicael Both/all, really.  Kevin was responding to user0000000 as clarification for the question which uses "counted" - but I don't see anything "counted" on that page aside from reputation, so I don't see how that was the page you're asking about

Comment: @Izkata Oh. Understood. I wrote "counted" because users are sorted in some way, which I didn't know.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked at meta.meta.stackoverflow.com :P, after all we are talking about meta stackoverflow.

Comment: @CommuSoft You mean on meta.stackexchange.com? ;-)

Comment: @nicael: As long as it is one meta level higher ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is based on your voting activity + posting activity (question, answers *and* comments) + edits made, over the past 60 days, but the exact formula is not published.

By all accounts, the formula is rather straightforward, however, just adding up all activity.

See [How is meta participation calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145151/how-is-meta-participation-calculated)

Comment: "but the exact formula is not published" - Aha.